# Pointer to functor

Tags: c++, function, functor

Let we have the following class:

```
class Functor{
    int even;
    int odd;
    Functor(int even, int odd){
        this->even=even;
        this->odd=odd;
    }
    void operator()(int x){
         if (x%2==0) even+=x;
         else odd+=x;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Functor* e= new Functor(0,0);//Now we have pointer to instance of Functor
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**
Let we have pointers to function `foo` and instance of Functor `e`, such that `(*foo)` and function defined by `operator()` in `Functor` have the same signatures. How we can do that `foo` have pointed to `void (*e)(int x)` without explicit rewriting implementation of `void (*e)(int x)`?

Comment: I think you're looking for `std::function`.

Comment: @chris Actually, many thaks!

Comment: Please include `foo` in your code, instead of describing how it would look.